# Disk burner software supporting Label Tag

Tags: software-recommendation, printing, burning

Is there a burner software that could use the Label Tag technology? Brasero and K3B don't seem to have that option.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

DVD burner LiteON iHAS524

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no Linux software available that supports Liteon's proprietary `labeltag` feature; the native Linux version of `Nero` has been [discontinued](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE0MjI). It was announced on the [official site](http://www.nero.com/eng/support-linux4-faq.html) that:

> As of March 27, 2012, Nero Linux 4 and the technical support for the product (and its family including Nero Linux 3) is no longer available.

However, this version of `Nero` in fact never supported the `labeltag` feature, as was revealed when a technical support question was raised on the [official forums](http://forum.my.nero.com/index.php?showtopic=8852).

The `labeltag` feature is unlikely to ever be in any native application, as the [official word](http://www.nero.com/eng/support-linux4-faq.html) is that the source code 'won't be published' and the specifications of the technology won't be able to be obtained.

`Nero 8` comes with the [Liteon burner](http://us.liteonit.com/us/dvd-internal/item/internal/ihas524), but very few cd burning applications will work properly under `Wine`, so unfortunately there is no real way of using `labeltag` under Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Damn LiteOn for no going open source...:(. Same issue goes for Nero (one of the most complete disk burners available) I just don't get it why a disk burning software has to cost money. It's such a basic operation. They should not wonder if a lot of pirated copies exist around the world. Thanks again for the answer. You got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried lightscribe?

http://www.thepowerbase.com/2011/10/lightscribe-in-linux-make-gorgeous-discs-in-ubuntu/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LightScribe

http://saraithegeek.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/lightscribe-for-ubuntu/

Comment: Lightscribe is not the same as LableTag: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabelTag